# Discord.js using interval and clearinterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Why is my code not working? I try when someone says: spam the bot begins spamming (it does but it will not stop) How can I fix this problem?

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  

let interval;

if (msg.content === 'yoyo') { 
  // ...
  if (!interval) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      msg.channel.send('yo')
        .catch(console.error);
    }, 1 * 5000);
  } else {
    message.channel.send('yo already running');
  }
}

if (msg.content === 'stop') {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = 1 * 1000000;
}
});
```

Comment: Be aware that this is against [Discords Terms of Service](https://discord.com/developers/docs/legal) - "You shall not ... use the API or SDK in connection with any Applications that include any malware or other harmful code or **that facilitate spamming in any way...**".

Comment: It seems to create a new interval on each event, just move that `let interval` outside your handler.

Comment: Spamming is illegal in Discord and is against their Terms of Service. If your code is for that purpose, delete it immediately and remove this question.

Comment: it was a concept, i wanted to make a "daily message" thing, couldn't come up with another word for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awnser to my question was to remove the `let interval` outside my handler. It was creating a new interval at each event.